# Как добавить behaviour на Яндекс карту в React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yandex-maps-api

Мне требуется отключить скролл зум, но при его отключении, карту больше двигать не получается.
Я делаю так.

`behaviors: ["disable('scrollZoom')"],`

Но кажется, что неправильно. Документации нет нормальной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Вместо `behaviors: ["disable('scrollZoom')"],`

Пишем  `behaviors: ["drag"],`